# PHP selectbox with onchange action

Tags: php, arrays, forms, onchange

I am struggling with this problem for week now.
 What I would like to achieve is have a select box on website and when I change value of that selectbox I would like to show/hide some fields for filling in (selectbox function works so I am not putting code here).

Actually I was thinking if I can pass value from vlan variable to other field variable when changing selection of the selectbox and then make a check condition on that new variable, any help would be appreciated (By the way, I want to keep as much as possible to current code since I am editing application which has many dependencies which I do not intend to brake;))

```
$vlan=array("0"=>my_("NO"),
  "1"=>my_("YES"));

insert($f,selectbox($vlan,
       array("name"=>"field","onChange"=>$field),
        $field=key($vlan)));

if ($field == "1") {
insert($f,input_text(array("name"=>"vlannr",
                       "value"=>"0",
                       "size"=>"4",
                       "maxlength"=>"4")));
}
else {
insert($f,textbr(my_("NO VLAN")));
}
```

Ok so I got the part where I assign value from array $vlan to another variable. Now I need to display new form whenever the variable changes to 1 and hide it when it changes back to 0. Any ideas ? (page can be reloaded , I do not care about that)

Comment: No wonder you are having problems. You've abstracted the HTML way too much.

Comment: Why not use AJAX to populate the combobox using a JSON result instead of rebuilding the page each time (which is what I assume you are doing?)

Comment: as I said , I need to stick with the existing code since rebuilding whole app would take ages for me , I do not have that much time and knowledge, I am just asking if its possible to do with current code ?